# Graphics card supports up to OpenGL 4.4, but Saints Row 4 (requires OpenGL 4.1) doesn't work with it

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I'm new to Open Source and need some help. I have been trying to figure this out all week. I'm having problems getting my OpenGL to work properly. My graphics card is supporting up to OpenGL 4.4. For playing Saints Row 4 I need 4.1 but that is saying it doesn't work.

My System Specs are:

- Intel Core 2 Duo e6420 OC'd to 2.96ghz
- EVGA GTX 750ti FTW ACX
- 4 GB of DDR3 RAM 1600mhz; will be getting 4 GB more to get to 8 GB soon.
- Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia drivers for your card?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
Because you have a very powerful card - the latest drivers might be better.
Install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers for the GEFORCE GTX 750 Ti.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password.

Execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

In case you already had NVIDIA drivers installed ... remove them before.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```